# Issue with protection level when serializing

Tags: c#, xml

I am doing a little program just to further learn xml serialization in wich i save id,name,age that belong to an object named Person. But somehow it throws an exception ( xmlTeste.Person is inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed.). How can i improve my code? The expected result is an xml file being created with the object Person.

The object Person:

```
    class Person
{
        #region Variables

    private int id = 0;
    private string name = string.Empty;
    private int idade = 0; //it's age in portuguese

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public int Idade //again... means age
    {
        get { return idade; }
        set { idade = value; }
    }

    #endregion
 }
```

My class to manage xml serialization

```
    class XMLController
{
    private static void SerializeAndSaveObject(XmlSerializer writer, Person item)
    {
        var path = "C://Folder//teste.xml";
        FileStream file = File.Create(path);

        writer.Serialize(file, item);
        file.Close();
    }

    public static void SaveFile(Person person)
    {
        SerializeAndSaveObject(new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person)), pessoa);//here is where i am having the error
       //An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
      //Additional information: xmlTeste.Pessoa is inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed.
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
        private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Person p = new Person
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "DEFEF",
            Idade = 2 //means age
        };
        xmlTeste.XMLController.SaveFile(p);


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Person` is an internal class. That's the "protection level" the exception is talking about. In C#, `internal` is the default, if you don't specify a protection level explicitly.

> Only public types can be processed

If it can only process public types, and you want it to process your type, try making your type public. The serialization code can't do anything with your class because the serialization code doesn't have access to your class -- internal means nobody outside of its own assembly has access to it.

Define your class like so:

```
public class Person {
...
```

Comment: I spent hours looking for the mistake and it was so obvious... Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Updated, tx